# How to add curved titles (text) inside of bars? - CircularPercentIndicator / Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am working on a project and I am creating a dashboard of sorts, the problem is I am having trouble finding a visually aesthetic way to present the titles of the stacked circularpercentindicators.

My thoughts right now is that I want to try adding the titles inside the bars with a wrap effect, so that the titles are essentially completely inside the the represented bars, following the same radius as the correlated cpi.

My code:

```
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CircularPercentIndicator(
      radius: 170.0,
      animation: true,
      animationDuration: 1200,
      lineWidth: 15.0,
      percent: totAggr,
      center: CircularPercentIndicator(
        radius: 150.0,
        lineWidth: 12.5,
        animation: true,
        percent: btc,
        center: CircularPercentIndicator(
          radius: 130.0,
          lineWidth: 12.5,
          animation: true,
          percent: eth,
          center: CircularPercentIndicator(
            radius: 110,
            lineWidth: 12.5,
            percent: alt,
            center: totAggr > 0.51
                ? Image.asset('assets/logos/bull.png')
                : Image.asset('assets/logos/bear.png'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            progressColor: Colors.green,
          ),
          circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.butt,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          progressColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.butt,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        progressColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      footer: const Text(
        "BULL/BEAR",
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17.0),
      ),
      circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.butt,
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      progressColor: Colors.green,
    );
  }
}
```

This is what my code currently looks like, with the exception that in the outer ring, i have added an example of what i am thinking i want to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flutter_circular_text](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_circular_text) package with Stack.

```dart
CircularText(
  children: [
    TextItem(
      text: Text(
        "total age....",
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.blue,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
      space: 6,//play with it
      startAngle: -40, //play with it
      startAngleAlignment: StartAngleAlignment.center,
      direction: CircularTextDirection.clockwise,
    ),
  ],
  radius: 125,
  position: CircularTextPosition.inside,
  backgroundPaint: Paint()..color = Colors.grey.shade200,
),
```

You can also use CustomPaint for this.

Comment: You can check [pskink's gist](https://gist.github.com/pskink/aa0b0c80af9a986619845625c0e87a67)

Comment: I am trying to add this circular text code after the "Center:" position on the circularpercentindicator, and then adding the next cpi after the text code, but i am getting the error, too many arguments.  is there a better placement for this? or a better way to implement?

Comment: `too many arguments.` check the method and class. Center widget only takes `child`. Try with `Positioned` widget for stack child

Comment: Oh man, I should have maybe prefaced this, with the fact that I am still actually learning flutter and this is one of my first projects of my very own. I am still struggling with this implementation.

Comment: try to play with the [example code](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

Comment: looked at it with fresh eyes and got it sorted.  Thanks.